# What is sufficient evidence for Dependent Care Account reimbursement?

Tags: tax-deduction, dependents, child-care

I'm attempting to submit a claim for my Dependent Care Account.  The expenses are the salary for my infant daughter's nanny.  I uploaded the pay stubs I got from the payroll company I use.  However, the claim was denied with this message:

> The receipt submitted does not provide the information we need to substantiate this expense. The IRS requires you to provide us with documentation from the provider which includes the date(s) the expense was incurred, the description of services, the person to whom the services were provided to and the amount charged. Resubmit your form with appropriate proof for this expense.

Would the signed employee contract, which specifies the duties and weekly hours, suffice?

Comment: I'd submit the contract *and* see if you can get the timesheets the payroll is based off. I presume you're tracking hours in some way to generate the payroll?

Answer (score 1):

Tell your payroll provider that you need to submit your nanny's wages for an fsa reimbursement. They deal with this all the time and have a letter with all of the relevant info that you can give to your fsa provider. At least that's the way GTM Payroll does it. Assuming the other major payroll services do the same or similar thing.